# Inequality regarding exponential function

Tags: inequality, functional-inequalities

For every positive $x$ and for every $n$ show that $(1+\sqrt{\frac{x}{n}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{x}{n}})e^{n\arctan{\frac{x}{n}}}>e^x$.

I plotted it, it seems that the inequality holds. Any ideas how to prove this?

Comment: I tried doing something with the left side, but everything I do brings me to something that is less than $e^x$. For example, $n\arctan(\frac{x}{n})<x$, for all $n$.

Comment: For large enough $x$, LHS < RHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality $$(1+\sqrt{\frac{x}{n}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{x}{n}})e^{n\arctan{\frac{x}{n}}}>e^x$$ only holds for a limited range $0<x<r_n$ where $r_n$ is the solution of $$f(x,n)=(1+\sqrt{\frac{x}{n}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{x}{n}})e^{n\arctan{\frac{x}{n}}}-e^x=0$$ Numerically $$r_1=2.58234$$ $$r_2=3.29207$$ $$r_3=3.93284$$ $$r_4=4.51660$$ $$r_5=5.05721$$